# Why this code prints out RValue instead of LValue

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

I was testing code out and got stuck on this.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void check(T&& other) {
    std::cout << "Rvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void check(T& other) {
    std::cout << "Lvalue" << std::endl;
}

template<typename T>
void call(T other) {
    check(std::forward<T>(other));
}

int main() {    
    std::string t = "Cool";
    call(t);
}
```

Output:

```
RValue
```

Why is the output of this "RValue"? I did pass a LValue and when it forwarded, didn't it forward as a LValue? Why did it call the RValue function of check?

Comment: You're already on the right trail with the `perfect-forwarding` tag you put on the question.

Answer (score 0):

To use `std::forward` properly, your argument type should be `T &&`, not `T`. Fix it like this:

```cpp
template<typename T>
void call(T&& other) {
    check(std::forward<T>(other));
}
```

Then we get the expected result.

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e6478h35E)

[Reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) for `std::forward`

> When t is a forwarding reference (a function argument that is declared
> as an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified function template
> parameter), this overload forwards the argument to another function
> with the value category it had when passed to the calling function.